# Proving a variable as discrete random (confusing question)

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, random-variables

A box contains 3 white and 3 black marbles. In a game, 3 marbles are randomly selected from the box. The score (X) is equivalent to the getting of 10 white marbles. Show that X is a discrete random variable.

*(I know that the probabilities have to be added to 1 for it to be a discrete random variable. Thats ok. My main issue here is the question itself. They say you take 3 marbles at once. From a total of 6 marbles. But then they are asking probability of taking 10 white marbles. So is it some game where the marbles are replaced and the game goes for more than one round etc.? I was beginning to think the question was wrong bcoz of how confusing it was..)*

Comment: What is the source of this horror?

Comment: source as in where i got the question from? I was practising random questions from past semester test papers for an upcoming test. So this was in one of the papers.

Comment: As it is, the question is at best nonsensical (until "selected from the box", everything is standard, after it nothing makes sense anymore). If really this was part of a test, well...